# Dimensionality Reduction. How to explain dynamics of feature subset based on all features data?

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science-model, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have features: `f1..f1000`. I want to explain dynamics of particular features subset: `f1-f5` based on all features data (based on `f1..f1000`).

Preferably I think of something like ***"partial PCA"***, where some Principal Components created on all features will explain dynamics only of 5 of them (not all of them).

If you know any kind of such **Dimensionality Reduction** technique I would be very glad for your help. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking: What do you mean by explaining dynamics of a featureset?

Comment: Ok, that's a fancy way of saying - explain variance of the subset of features by all features